# jquery tablesorter not working on IIS production server

Tags: jquery, iis, tablesorter

I have tablesorter plugin in several pages in my application and it works fine on localhost When I run it from inside visual studio. But when I publish to on IIS on the production server it doesn't work at all!

I have no idea what might be the problem.

Comment: Host the js files on the server and/or you don't have the correct paths for the files in production.

Comment: but the path is relative and the js file contains script for other stuff that work fine.only sorting is not working

Comment: Then show the code of the sorting or there is no way for anyone to answer this question

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has nothing to do with IIs.  jQuery is a client side, browser based javascript framework.  It does not run on the server.

If you deployed your application and it stopped working it is because of one of the following things:

- Your paths in your html are wrong -- the path locally is not the same as the path on the server
- You are doing AJAX calls and one of the following:

  - Security / Rights on the prod server.
  - Cross site scripting error (the browser does not allow them).
  - The path has changed on the server (same as my first point above)
- You did not deploying all the files
- You are using a different browser